# Angular does not resolve scripts source map

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, source-maps

I have a library. The library is a folder containing a minified file, source files(from which the minified file is generated). A source map file of the minified file is also present in the folder and is referenced at the end of bundled minified file. I wanted it to available globally. So, I included it in scripts array (architect:build:options:scrips) in angular.json. I passed only the path to the minified file in the array, something like this:

```
 "scripts": [
          "src/MyFolder/myLib.min.js"
        ]
```

Now, the sourcemap generated for scripts.js redirects me to minified file(myLib.min.js) during debugging instead of my library source files. Angular is not resolving the library sourcemap file. How do i enable it?

Comment: I think you need to enable it in the angular.json file, there should be something like sourceMap / vendorSourceMap if i remember correctly

Comment: Yes, I included the vendorSourceMap tag which loaded the source files. But they are not prettified. The import statements are not interpreted and throws of an error
"cannot use import statement outside a module"